# "+" symbol contain email file name is not opening

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to open email message by providing URL as below

```
mailUrl = "/Inbox/test%20mail%20%2B%20to%20verify%20%2B%20symbol.EML"

oXMLHttp.open("PROPFIND", mailUrl, false, strUser, strPass);

%20 - space

%2B - +
```

It returns `file not found` error, but file is there. The issue I am facing is, whenever `+` symbol used in file name, getting file not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Because that naming convention are illegal. Avoid using non-alphanumeric characters in file names. The use of these characters can cause problems and issues, plus, file name can't be longer  than 128 characters.

Read this link below, they are helpful to understand and list the symbol that need to be avoid in file name:

1. [Standard naming conventions for electronic records, rule 13](http://www.recordsmanagement.ed.ac.uk/InfoStaff/RMstaff/RMprojects/PP/FileNameRules/Rule13.htm)
2. [Characters to Avoid in Directories and Filenames](http://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/web/cms/characters-avoid/)
3. [Illegal characters to avoid in filenames](https://support.filetransporter.com/article/AA-00410)

Maybe you can try to sanitize input (file name) before passing to `oXMLhttp.open()` function such like this :

```
string mailUrl = "/Inbox/test%20mail%20%2B%20to%20verify%20%2B%20symbol.EML"

private static string SanitizeFileName(string name)
{
string invalidChars = Regex.Escape( new string( Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() ) );
string invalidReStr = string.Format( @"[{0}]+", invalidChars );
return Regex.Replace( name, invalidReStr, "_" );
}

validFileName = SanitizeFileName(mailUrl);

oXMLHttp.open("PROPFIND", validFileName, false, strUser, strPass);
```

Comment: Hi RobbNesp, Thanks for your suggestion. Actually whenever user send mail, the mail will be stored in the format of  <subject line>.EML in the exchange server. We have two functionalities, one will list all unread mails in the page and other one when clicked on specific list, will open body content of that mail. For displaying list, we are using search and giving till folder path. So its displaying all the list including "+" symbol file name. But when opening that particular email, we are facing this error.

Comment: I suggest you to sanitize it to remove illegal characters.

Comment: yeah, I tried this URL also, "/Inbox/test mail + to verify + symbol.EML". Same file not found status.

Comment: Update and merge my answer. Sorry mod, for double posting the answer.

Comment: @E.Veerabhadran that is not sanitize, what you did are decode the  URL encode. Check my update answer, which the "+" will be replace with "_".